# Importing AddressBook data into the iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Is there an easy way to import AddressBook data into the iPhone Simulator?

Right now my only assumption is to manually modify the SQLite files found in the */Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Library/AddressBook*.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I was looking for the exact solution, and this worked perfectly for me on a non-jailbroken phone.  It works by extracting your iPhone address book from an unencrypted backup.

- Quit the iOS Simulator
- Download [iPhone/iPod Touch Backup Extractor](http://supercrazyawesome.com/)
- Run it, and select the last option "iOS Files"
- Create a folder on your desktop and extract all files to that folder
- When complete, go to your extract folder and navigate to Library/AddressBook
- Copy both files (AddressBook.sqlitedb and AddressBookImages.sqlitedb) to: 
  ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/{SDK}/Library/AddressBook
- Run the Contacts application in iOS Simulator

Comment: plus me makes three it doesn't work for (using iOS 6.0 simulator)

Comment: Works for me on 6.1 simulator. One note though: remove the -shm and -wal files in the simulator folder or the copied address book won't be used.

Comment: @Nick how did you get it to work?  even if i remove the sm and wal files, the simulator blows out my contacts when I start the contacts app.

Comment: @ChrisTruman I didn't do anything special. Quit the simulator, go through all the steps here, start the simulator again, visit contacts app.

Comment: It works, but you have to delete all files in the folder first.

Comment: Did not work with Xcode 6.  Then again, maybe I'm using the wrong (of dozens!) Address Book folder.  Can someone update the answer to give a better path for Xcode6.1?  Thanks!

Comment: To clarify: I copied to both `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Library/AddressbBook` and `.../7.1-64/...` -- as well as `.../User/Library/AddressBook` -- then launched the iPhone 5s (7.1) Sim, and I still only had the 6 "comes with" contacts.  Xcode 6.1

Comment: haven't had to try yet. give it a shot and leave your findings in the comments.

Comment: Great Solution. But this is not working in IOS8 / 9 in xcode 7.1

Answer (score 10):

DummyContacts is an application that allows you to add Contacts to AddressBook and can be a handy tool for all iOS devices as well as simulators. DummyContacts is a life saver and pretty easy to setup. One click adds 100 records and one click also removes all 100. It also supports iOS6. So check it out at : https://github.com/Janak-Nirmal/DummyContacts .

Answer (score 6):

Just sign in to your iCloud account on the simulator and turn "Contacts on" under iCloud. All your contacts, photos etc will appear on the simulator. Obviously, this assumes you are backing up your contacts to iCloud on your iPhone. Hope it helps!

Comment: Ha! Wicked easy solution. Nice one.

Comment: If you're not using iCloud but use Google for example, export contacts from Google, and import them into icloud.com. Then enable iCloud on the simulator.

Comment: This was an easy solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

As Marc pointed in his answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27582281/4598931 for a similar question it can be done just exporting contacts to vCard and drag and drop the generated file to iphone simulator.

Answer (score 2):

or if your iPhone isn't jailbroken, you can extract the sqlite db from a backup using the shell script here: http://0xced.blogspot.com/2009/01/using-your-own-address-book-in-iphone.html

(note you'll need to change the simulator path it copies it to, as in the current SDK it's a bit different due to the addition of the OS version folder - easiest thing would be to just change it to your home directory and copy manually from there)

Answer (score 0):

Right this is the only way i know with a "legit" iPhone

But if you have a jailbroken iPhone, you can download the iPhone AddressBook database with ssh, and replace the simulator one by the iphone one.