# Is there possibility to create virtual address book in my simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, addressbook

I want to import contacts from address book to my app.Here I want to check whether my functionality works well .Is it possible to create virtual address book in simulator....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing AddressBook data into the iPhone Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901132/importing-addressbook-data-into-the-iphone-simulator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Contacts app in the iOS Simulator, isn't there? So launch it and create a few contacts.

Comment: How can I be more specific?? When you launch iOS Simulator, look for the Contacts app on it's home screen and launch it. Click + and add a new contact. Repeat a few times.