# Adding a large number of contacts to the iPhones contact list

Tags: objective-c, contacts

I am developing 1 iPhone contact related application .
To check the overhead I have to add a large number of contacts.
Is there any way to do that without manually entering data

Comment: Do you want to add it to your simulator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing AddressBook data into the iPhone Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901132/importing-addressbook-data-into-the-iphone-simulator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add many contacts to your simulator using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901132/importing-addressbook-data-into-the-iphone-simulator?answertab=votes#tab-top), adding many contacts to your device just set them up on the mac and synchronise them via gmail oder iCloud.